# ITextSharp - working with images

Tags: c#, .net, itext

How I extract text from image using ITextSharp? it is possible?
if not, how do this? 
thanks.

Comment: Text from an *image* or text from a *PDF*?

Comment: For text from an *image* you'll want to look into OCR (optical character recognition), see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870280/ocr-for-net

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=475759) for some custom-written code that might solve this problem for you, or point you in the right direction.